# Match Row based on previously available date to second table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have two tables of data I would like to join: Transactions and User History

Transactions

| user_id | transaction_id | price | transaction_date | redeemed_points |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | rztgdh | 0.00 | 2022-10-07 10:25:43 | 1500 |
| 54321 | lfhskfdj | 0.00 | 2022-10-11 17:52:16 | 2100 |

User History

| user_id | time_updated | point_balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 2022-09-26 18:15:38 | 3160 |
| 12345 | 2022-09-29 13:19:22 | 3250 |
| 12345 | 2022-10-07 10:25:45 | 1750 |
| 54321 | 2022-10-05 19:43:29 | 5000 |
| 54321 | 2022-10-11 17:52:18 | 2900 |

The transactions table should be the left join table and I want to add a column to it with the point balance prior to the start of the transaction the most up to date previous timestamp. Meaning the first transaction from user 12345 should have an additional column with the last available point balance from the user history table prior to the transaction, in this case 3250.

The final table should look like this
Transactions with new column

| user_id | transaction_id | price | transaction_date | redeemed_points | points_start |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | rztgdh | 0.00 | 2022-10-07 10:25:43 | 1500 | 3250 |
| 54321 | lfhskfdj | 0.00 | 2022-10-11 17:52:16 | 2100 | 5000 |

Any help is much appreciated.

I have been unable to come up with a solution that would be close to what I want to achieve and be automated enough. I am working with datasets of about 200k rows, any manual work is not possible.

Comment: Is the data formatted as date or as string/text?  Would make a difference for options.

Comment: It is formatted as date. It can be formatted as string if needed

Answer (score 2):

Use SUMIFS with a nested AGGREGATE:

```
=SUMIFS(J:J,H:H,A2,I:I,AGGREGATE(14,7,$I$2:$I$6/(($H$2:$H$6=A2)*($I$2:$I$6<D2)),1))
```

[image]